# I am sorry to be a pain for you

Tags: meaning

> I am sorry to be a pain for you

does it mean the same as

> I am sorry for causing you pain?

If not? What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is probably the minced version of "a pain in the ass".

Comment: Yes, "I am sorry for causing you pain."  But note that "pain" has many metaphorical meanings, beyond the sensation of physical discomfort.

Comment: Lack of context. It could just as well be..."I am sorry to be a PIA about this..."

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

These senses of **pain**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pain)

> to **torment**, to cause **distress**

As in:

*I am sorry to torment or cause you distress.*

Comment: Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

In this context, a pain someone who is annoying, not usually causing physical pain. From [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pain)

> 5. *Informal* A source of annoyance; a nuisance:
>      *Stuffing all these envelopes is a real pain.*

I believe it comes from a shortening of "pain in the neck" or "pain in the ass", which are idioms for minor annoyances.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.